# How to create a model in Java for Dynamic mongodb Schema?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

With Relational Databases, I could create a model in Java since I know How many columns a table has and their respective names.
But MongoDb doesn't work often with such static schema(If I'm not wrong). So, I want to create a model in Java that hold all the data and convert it into JSON and sent it to the response as a web service.

But I could do by returning just Document or DBObject objects. But It's converting **ID** as

```
"_id": {
        "timestamp": 1505194179,
        "machineIdentifier": 13503772,
        "processIdentifier": 3816,
        "counter": 1819499,
        "date": 1505194179000,
        "time": 1505194179000,
        "timeSecond": 1505194179
    }
```

Where I just need an ID value for further to make network calls to use this identifier.

So I want to know a best practice or strategy in order to achieve this. I use spring boot.
I'me very much new to Mongodb with Spring boot. So, bear me If my understanding is wrong.

Edit: In Spring boot, it's necessary to define entity class to access the data but I just want to know other way where I don't want a model to be predefined but it should be dynamic as the schema in mongodb.

Comment: So what is so inconvenient about it? Please continue. If it's so inconvenient then you really should explain why! Otherwise we have no idea of what direction to point you in. Maybe you should learn to live with it. Maybe you need several strict models and type discriminators. But your "question" really tells us nothing about "what you really need". And as a "general discussion" it's really not that useful. So you really should get on with explaining exactly what you think you need and why.

Comment: @NeilLunn I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: So am I to take that as your "only real issue" at the end of all of that is that `ObjectId` values are not presently serializing correctly for you when used with `DBObject`or `Document` classes? So how are you actually serializing these documents? I presume you expect JSON output? Both of those classes actually have a `.toJSON()` method ( as does `ObjectId` ) so this rather indicates an issue in your code. So show the code that is serializing the data.

Comment: @NeilLunn In Spring boot, it's necessary to define entity class to access the data but I just want to know other way where I don't want a model to be predefined but it should be dynamic as the schema in mongodb. This is the soul purpose, I've asked the question for. Thank you

Comment: This is my use case as well . In javascript it pretty easy . That's why people are good with Nodejs and MongDB compared to Spring with MongoDb. But this is just my opinion

Comment: @xpioneer That's true. MongoDB can be pretty much accepted with NodeJS but when we happen to work with SpringBoot with Mongo, what can be the best practice is what makes me curious